# Can Meteor be run on a private server and domain name?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use meteor on my existing website. I will be using meteor for a new page on my website. I was wondering if it is possible to implement meteor's api on my own server and domain name and also with my own database (MongoDB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to bundle the Meteor application for deployment on your own server.
Check this out http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorbundle

Another way to go is to use https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh
I haven't tried it myself, but intend to. Will post an update whenever I have.

Third option (and one I would strongly consider) is to use a PaaS like AppFog or Heroku.
Here is how you'd do it on AppFog http://blog.philkershaw.me/2012/06/deploy-meteor-to-appfog.html